# Reusing groovy script in jenkins Declarative pipeline file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to reuse groovy script loaded once in Jenkinsfile.

Right now this is what I am doing

```
            steps {
                script {
                    def util = load("${env.WORKSPACE}/scripts/build_util.groovy")
                    util.runStep1()
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    def util = load("${env.WORKSPACE}/scripts/build_util.groovy")
                    util.runStep2()
                }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    def util = load("${env.WORKSPACE}/scripts/build_util.groovy")
                    util.runStep3()
                }
            }
```

I am doing the same again in post build with multiple script blocks step to send mails.

Is there a better way to do this? I cannot use [shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

Comment: Have you tried only executing `def util = load("${env.WORKSPACE}/scripts/build_util.groovy")` once? That should work. Alternatively, all of those could fit in one `steps { script { ... } }` block anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you just need to load the script only once.

```
def util = load("${env.WORKSPACE}/scripts/build_util.groovy")
```

You can create a stage and load the script there and store in a variable and then do something like this:-

```
stage('Environment') {
     agent  { node { label 'master' } }
        steps {
          script {
                def util = load("${env.WORKSPACE}/scripts/build_util.groovy")
               }
            }
         }
post {
        // Things that we want done regardless of pipeline's outcome
        //
        always {

            // Push the overall statistics from all the stages to InfluxDB
            //
            node (LINUX_BUILD_NODE){
                script{
                    //Mail sending function call
                    //
                    util.runStep1()
                    util.runStep2()
                    util.runStep3()                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use "**util**" in any stage to call the different functions.

Comment: can you please rate the answer also :)

Comment: Hi, any way to load some code for "triggers" section ? (this cannot be inside "script" I think)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the variable `util` at top level, then assign value to it in the first stage, after than you can use it in any stage.

```
def util;

pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage('one') {
        steps {
            script {
                util = load("${env.WORKSPACE}/scripts/build_util.groovy")
                util.runStep1()
            }
        }
      }
      post {
        util.xxxx
      }

      stage('two') {
        steps {
            script {
                util = load("${env.WORKSPACE}/scripts/build_util.groovy")
                util.runStep2()
            }
        }
      }
      post {
        util.xxxx
      }

   }

   post {
        util.xxxx
   }
}
```

Comment: Can we have a 'pre' hook for initialisation. If pipeline fails and I restart it from stage `two`, this approach breaks.